# Как работать с сервером Apache, запущенном на VirtualBox, через NAT?

Tags: apache, virtualbox, nat

Например, если Apache настроен на отображение двух доменов: site1 и site2, как их увидеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть имя машины - x. Тогда команды

```
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/Protocol" TCP
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/GuestPort" 80
VBoxManage setextradata x "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/HostPort" 8080
```

настроят отображение портов на гостевую машину. Если прописать в /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   site1
127.0.0.1   site2
```

то по адресу `http://site1:8080` и `http://site2:8080` будут доступны виртуальные хосты Apache.

P.S. Нужно иметь ввиду, что после отображения портов, доступиться ним можно будет только к гостевой машине.